# Showing that $\nabla_Xf = Xf$

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, smooth-manifolds, connections

Let $\nabla$ be a connection on a smooth manifold $M$, $X$ a vector field on $M$, and $f$ a real-valued function on $M$. I would like to show that
$$\nabla_Xf = Xf.$$

In addition to showing this technically, why is this true geometrically? Covariant derivatives allow us to connect nearby tangent spaces, but what is the interpretation when $f$ is a function and so no tangent spaces are involved?

Comment: You should begin by telling us your definition of "connection in $TM$". I am asking about this because, in general, by "connection" people understand in fact "covariant derivative", and a covariant derivative has the property that you are asking about **by definition**.

Comment: @AlexM. I am using the definition where if $\nabla_X Y$ is a covariant derivative and $X, Y$ are vector fields then the connection is $C^\infty$ linear in $X$ and $\mathbb{R}$ linear in $Y$.

Comment: What you are writing is the definition of $\nabla _XY$, where $Y$ is a vector field. $\nabla_Xf$ is completely different from $\nabla_XY$.

Comment: The definition of $Xf$ does not require a connection, so technically it should not be written as $\nabla_Xf$. It’s better to write

Comment: A connection in the tangent bundle by definition only acts on vector fields. It does not act on functions. **However** when we decide to extend the definition to the full tensor algebra we **by defintion** require the equality (as I’m sure I mentioned to you in a previous answer of mine ot in a comment there). So there’s nothing to prove. Why introduce more notation for things we already have a definition for? Because it makes equations look more “uniform” and its just convenient: I’d rather see $\nabla$’s all over rather than a whole mix of symbols.

Comment: This btw also coincides with what we usually call the trivial connection in a trivial vector bundle $M\times V$. But again, it’s a definition (the only thing to be proven is this actually gives a connection… but this is immediate).

Comment: @peek-a-boo Thank you, I did not know that this was true by definition.

Answer (score 0):

Actually，we can define the connection in each tensor bundle $T^{(k,l)}TM$ such that we can compute covariant derivatives of tensor fields. The smooth function $f$ can be seen as a $(0,0)$ type tensor field. Indeed, a linear connection is a principle of computing direction derivative. So the $\nabla_X f$ is the derivative of $f$ in the direction $X$.

Comment: A scalar function does not carry indices and is invariant with respect to coordinate transformation at a consistent geometrical point.